# Convert File Names into UTF

Tags: character-encoding

I have a folder full of sub folders and files which are named using Hebrew encoding (Windows XP - Windows-1255).
I now use Windows 7 and I want to convert all file names into UTF (Native Windows 7 which supports Hebrew characters).

Is there a tool to do so automatically?

Pay attention, I'm not after converting the internals of the file, only its file name.

Thanks!

Comment: What file system are they stored on? As far as I know, both FAT32 (LFN) and NTFS *enforce* Unicode, so having filenames stored in another encoding just should not happen.

Comment: NTFS. ON XP they don't enforce the use the default Encoding set on the control panel.

Comment: @Royi are you still around, and is your question still relevant for you?

Comment: @YisroelTech, Yea, a solution will always be great. Thank You.

Comment: @Royi is it music files filenames and properties being displayed as Gibberish characters? Something like à.ç.ååééñ

Comment: @YisroelTech, not music files but the same form of Gibberish.

Comment: Oh, ok. Because I managed to find an easy way to solve the problem for music files using the Mp3tag program. See little screen recording here https://streamable.com/xjzb0 now gotta find a program that does it for all kind of files

Comment: @Royi, I got a solution, but can you first post a sample of several filenames that you have? (because there are two different ways it becomes. I wanna know which kind you have.)

Comment: @YisroelTech, I think you better just write an answer here for the 2 cases you have. I will +1 the answers and then anybody can enjoy it.

Comment: Okay, I will and let me know if one of them does it for you.

Comment: If you have the raw bytes from a file name and know what they are supposed to represent, a table like https://cdn.rawgit.com/tripleee/8bit/master/encodings.html can help you figure out which encoding you are looking at.  From there it should be easy to find a tool to do the translation, or write a script of your own if you know how.

Comment: I searched for such a tool and was not able to find one. (except for music files which Mp3tag has an option "convert codepage"). Do you know of such a tool?

Comment: It should be about 2-3 lines of Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Background

What is needed to be done to fix this is to find some way to automatically know each of these Gibberish characters which Hebrew character they were before being getting that way.

I compiled to such lists of characters. I've seen both kinds of corruptions, sometimes it was using one set and sometimes the other. Here are both sets (and here it is pasted in separate rows, which is needed for what we 'll be doing: [Set 1](http://pastebin.com/P4qRGEL9) and [Set 2](http://pastebin.com/ChBLi6V8)):

1. à=א
   á=ב
   â=ג
   ã=ד
   ä=ה
   å=ו
   æ=ז
   ç=ח
   è=ט
   é=י
   ê=ך
   ë=כ
   ì=ל
   í=ם
   î=מ
   ï=ן
   ð=נ
   ñ=ס
   ò=ע
   ó=ף
   ô=פ
   õ=ץ
   ö=צ
   ÷=ק
   ø=ר
   ù=ש
   ú=ת
   ‚=ג
   „=ד
   ‡=א
   ˆ=צ
   ‰=ה
   ˜=ק
   ¯=ר
   Á=ח
   Â=ו
   È=י
   Ê=ז
   Ë=ט
   Ì=ם
   Í=ך
   Î=כ
   Ï=ל
   Ò=ס
   Ó=מ
   Ô=ן
   Ù=פ
   Ú=ע
   Û=ף
   Æ=.
   ¨=,
   ß='
   ¢="
2. Ç=א
   ü=ב
   é=ג
   â=ד
   ä=ה
   à=ו
   å=ז
   ç=ח
   ê=ט
   ë=י
   è=ך
   ï=כ
   î=ל
   ì=ם
   Ä=מ
   Å=ן
   É=נ
   æ=ס
   Æ=ע
   ô=ף
   ö=פ
   ò=ץ
   û=צ
   ù=ק
   ÿ=ר
   Ö=ש
   Ü=ת

---

### Got it Fixed!

To actually rename files and folders, I figured out an easy way to got this done using [**Bulk Rename Utility**](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php)

1. Open the programs and browse to the folder containing all the files with this kind of names.
   [image]
2. In the bottom of the interface, in the **Special** section, click on **Character Translations**
3. In the dialog that opens paste the whole list of the charachter set your files are displayed in from the Pastbin link above, and click **OK**
   [image]
4. In the **Filters** section, place a checkmark at **Subfolders** if you want to do more then one folder at a time.
5. Select all files and folder in the list (you should see the name it'll become after renaming it in the 2nd coulmn) and click **Rename**. And now all names should be displyed in Hebrew!
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Windows stores file names on disk in UTF-16 (two-byte code units, variable-length) encoding. This applies to FAT, FAT32, NTFS and exFAT.

It's unlike Linux/FreeBSD where filesystems have one-byte encoding, and it can be Windows-1255, UTF-8, ISO-8859-* etc.

UTF-16 is converted to ANSI (one-byte encoding) by Windows for some old non-Unicode software which is using old system calls like FindFirstFileA(), FindNextFileA() instead of new system calls FindFirstFileW(), FindNextFileW().

So all you need on Windows is to change "language for non-Unicode programs" setting in Control Panel / Regional and Language Settings. On-disk data is not affected.

Comment: UCS-2 is dead and not even a Unicode encoding.

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317748%28v=vs.85%29.aspx FAT and FAT32 use a system-specific encoding. NTFS and exFAT both use UTF-16.

Comment: FAT and FAT32 use UTF-16 in filenames as well. UTF-16 filenames are stored in LFNs (long filename records) and OEM-encoded filenames (i.e. converted from UTF-16 to single byte encoding using OEM code page, which you call system-specific encoding) are stored in SFNs (short filename records). DOS used only OEM encoding, and supported only SFNs, thus 8.3 filename limit.