# How to correctly decompress a file with ANSI coding so that the output file is with UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: compression, zip, 7-zip, utf-8

I have a .zip file which is a compressed folder and has ANSI encoding (I think, because I opened it with Notepad and it said that it has ANSI encoding). The file (folder) contains other files which have nonsensical characters (ż instead of š, đ instead of ą, etc.). So I decompressed it with it 7-Zip but the nonsensical characters stay. How to decompress the file so that the characters become sensical (have UTF-8 encoding)? I have tried searching for a solution but could not find. If there is an answer to this question already in this website, please write the link. My OS is Windows 10.
Solved:
Only the file names need to be changed. I found my answer here: [Convert File Names into UTF](https://superuser.com/questions/327816/convert-file-names-into-utf)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure that the specific file is something human-readable? Not all files are intended to be read by humans. If you unzip the file and is still not readable probably it is a "so called" binary file or even a text file that is still intended to be read by machines.
2. Normally the editor **Notepad** in your case, guesses the encoding, is not something you can be really sure without more information. Some editors are better than others, one editor called [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) could be a good choice for you (easy to use).
3. We should understand exactly what kind of file you are trying to read and for which purpose in order to tell you if this is human-readable or not.

Comment: The file contains Godot (a game engine) project files. I need to decompress the zip file so that I could import it in Godot. Now I saw that only the file names are gibberish, but the files themselves are not.

Answer (score 0):

WinRAR can do that.

Enter the archive, go to Options -> Name Encoding and choose what works for you. Decompress.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but now there are � where Lithuanian characters should be.

Comment: Extract some files with one encoding, others with a different one. No idea what the source PC was, so it's hard to say.